# How to select the <tr> which holds the <a> andchange the color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table structure:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="#" class="xx">one</a>
                </td>
                <td>Two</td>
                <td>Three</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="#" class="xx">Four</a>
                </td>
                <td>Five</td>
                <td>Six</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="#" class="xx">Seven</a>
                </td>
               <td>Eight</td>
                <td>Nine</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
 .yy
    {
     background-color: red;    
    }
```

Now the problem is if I click on the `<a>` its corresponding `<tr>` element (`<tr>` that holds the `<a>`) background should be red, again if I click on the same `<a>` it should come back to normal.
How to identify the the `<tr>` on which the `<a>` is clicked.

EDIT:
I tried:
$(".yy").not($(this).parent().parent()).removeClass("yy");
                $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("yy");
it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a').live('click', function(){

$(this).parent().parent() //this is how you select the <tr> that the <a> is in

//first .parent() gets the <td> second .parent() gets the <tr>

});
```

Let me know if you need more. There might be a better way but I'm not positive.

Comment: what is the live part for? couldn't he just do $('a').click or am I missing something

Answer (score 1):

I think [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) should get what you are looking for.

```
$('a').click(function() {
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   tr.toggleClass('yy');
});
```

This way you do not have to assume anything about how nested the anchor is in the containing `tr`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC9SF/)